# VNC Client - Server, Unable to connect to remote server

Tags: linux, vnc

[image]

I have a remote Linux server, I was trying to connect to it using TigerVNC, I can sucessfully connect to my remote server, when the server iptable is not running, but after I start running iptables, I am unable to connect to remote server using VNC

Error :  "The connection was refused by the host computer"

Connecting as **IP_ADDRESS::5901**

Do I need to add entry in iptables to all all to connect to VNC server, or any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: can you share the output of your iptables -L ?

Comment: I have attached the screenshot above...Thanks

Comment: In above pic I was trying to add one single source IP [10.8.96.119], but please ignore that,....I want all IPs should be able to connect.

Comment: You can also add 6000 or 6001 for the X Server port

Answer (score 0):

For VNC, you need to modify your rules as follows

```
for i in 0 1 2 3
do
  iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 580$i  -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 590$i  -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 600$i  -j ACCEPT
done
```

This is for 4 VNC connections. If you need more or less, you need to adjust the number of times the loop should run.

Comment: Does position matters in the IPTABLES,.....I already have some in that file.

Comment: Position matters as `iptables` entries get processed from top to bottom and process stops on the first matching rule. But if you try to introduce the same rule twice, I think the later coming one kicks the older rule out in the sequence of events.